# LC-3 Decimal to Binary Converter

Tags: loops, lc3

I have to create a program that converts the given user input (decimal) into its binary match when the user presses enter or exit when they press X. Can anyone give a pointer on how to start this assignment. We are required to use masks and loops, but I do not know where to start with this.

Comment: Do you have to store that binary value as a string in memory, or do you only need to print the binary value to the console?

Comment: it only needs to be printed to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this because there aren't a whole lot of examples of binary masks.

A binary mask is useful in assembly because it gives us the power to examine a single bit in a decimal or hex value.

Example: 
If we look at the decimal number **5** we know its binary value is **0101**, when we `AND R4, R4, R5` on our first loop we compare **1000** with **0101**. Since *bit[3]* is a zero in **0101** we then tell the LC3 simulator to print out an ASCII char "0". We then repeat the process with the next binary mask **0100**.

This can be a tricky concept to get at first so I would first look at a few examples of loops and bit masks.

[LC3 Bit Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987006/lc3-bit-counter/29992629#29992629)

[How do I write a program that prints out “Hello World”, 5 times using a loop in LC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600724/how-do-i-write-a-program-that-prints-out-hello-world-5-times-using-a-loop-in)

```
.ORIG x3000

    LEA R0, PROMPT
    PUTs                ; TRAP x22
    LD R0, ENTER
    OUT                 ; TRAP x21
    IN                  ; TRAP x23

    AND R5, R5, #0      ; clear R5
    ADD R5, R5, R0      ; Store the user input into R5

    AND R1, R1, #0      ; clear R1, R1 is our loop count
    LD R2, MASK_COUNT   ; load our mask limit into R2
    NOT R2, R2          ; Invert the bits in R2
    ADD R2, R2, #1      ; because of 2's compliment we have
                        ; to add 1 to R2 to get -4
WHILE_LOOP
    ADD R3, R1, R2      ; Adding R1, and R2 to see if they'll
                        ; will equal zero
    BRz LOOP_END        ; If R1+R2=0 then we've looped 4
                        ; times and need to exit

    LEA R3, BINARY      ; load the first memory location 
                        ; in our binary mask array
    ADD R3, R3, R1      ; use R1 as our array index and
                        ; add that to the first array location
    LDR R4, R3, #0      ; load the next binary mask into R4

    AND R4, R4, R5      ; AND the user input with the 
                        ; binary mask
    BRz NO_BIT
    LD R0, ASCII_ONE
    OUT                 ; TRAP x21
    ADD R1, R1, #1      ; add one to our loop counter
    BRnzp WHILE_LOOP    ; loop again
NO_BIT
    LD R0, ASCII_ZERO
    OUT                 ; TRAP x21

    ADD R1, R1, #1      ; add one to our loop counter
    BRnzp WHILE_LOOP    ; loop again
LOOP_END

    LD R0, ENTER
    OUT                 ; TRAP x21
    HALT                ; TRAP x25

; Binary Maps
BINARY  .FILL   b0000000000001000
        .FILL   b0000000000000100
        .FILL   b0000000000000010
        .FILL   b0000000000000001
        .FILL   b0000000000000000

; Stored Values
ENTER       .FILL   x000A
ASCII_ZERO  .FILL   x0030
ASCII_ONE   .FILL   x0031
MASK_COUNT  .FILL   x04     ; loop limit = 4
PROMPT      .STRINGZ "Enter a number from 0-9"

.END
```

Comment: The issues I have with this is it has to work for numbers greater than 9 and negative numbers as well, and it must also be in 16 bits.

Comment: I provided this code sample to help you get headed in the right direction. If you have specific questions about your modified code, you're welcome to post those questions as new posts. If this answer was helpful, please remember to make it as answered. Thanks.